# Making Conditional Formatting for a SUMIF filter in Google Sheets relative?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a handy little Google Sheet formula that applies a color given a summed total but I can't get that formula to be relative.  I suspect this is either an easy genius fix or currently impossible in Sheets.  Any help?

Sorry I can't post images, here's a rough simulation of my table a1 - b4

- John Doe | 25%
- Martha Roe | 25%
- John Doe | 75%
- Jane Doe | 25%

In the table above, I'm using Conditional formatting to "Format cells if..custom formula is..." and my formula sums up the values in Column B for John Roe and Martha Roe (Column A) and turns both the name and value cell red if that value exceeds 100%.  I use the formula below:

```
=sum(filter(B$1:$B4,A$1:A$4 = A1)) >= 100%
```

(Full credit to [Spreadsheetpro.net's article](http://spreadsheetpro.net/how-to-make-sumifs-countifs-averagifs-functions-in-google-spreadsheet/) for the intro SUMIFS, COUNTIFS, & AVERAGEIFS functions in Google Spreadsheet.)

Unfortunately, when I use this conditional formatting approach and drag that formula to the next cell in the row, it still thinks I mean A1 (not A2); it's just applying that original formula to multiple rows.  So right now I need to manually change the formula for each cell.  Maddening.

What I'd like to do is have it update relative to what cell it's in.    To make it easier, I'd be ok if there was a way to tell it in the formula *"use the cell I'm in"* (instead of specifying A1).

1. Is there a way I can fix my current formula so Google knows that A1is relative? OR, barring that
2. Is there a way to use conditioning formatting with a formula so it knows the use the current cell in the formula?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to not drag the formula per se, but apply it to the range you require. The formula will be propagated across that range, respecting absolute and relative references as if you were dragging an in-cell spreadsheet formula over a range.

In your case, I think you just need to apply:

`=SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B$4,$A$1:$A$4=$A1))>=100%`

to the range `A1:B4`.

It can help conceptualise what is going on by just plugging that formula into a spare spreadsheet cell, and dragging it over a 2x4 range of cells.